# Get subexpression strings from output of pretty() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Is there a good way to get all the subexpressions in the output of a pretty() call in single-line strings?  `subexpr()` returns a single subexpression, but I'd like to get all of them.  Here's what pretty() returns:

```
syms x
s = solve(x^4 + 2*x + 1, x,'MaxDegree',3);
pretty(s)


/         -1         \
|                    |
|           2    1   |
|    #2 - ---- + -   |
|         9 #2   3   |
|                    |
|   1         #2   1 |
| ---- - #1 - -- + - |
| 9 #2         2   3 |
|                    |
|        1    #2   1 |
| #1 + ---- - -- + - |
\      9 #2    2   3 /

where

                 /   2       \
         sqrt(3) | ---- + #2 | 1i
                 \ 9 #2      /
   #1 == ------------------------
                    2

         / sqrt(11) sqrt(27)   17 \1/3
   #2 == | ----------------- - -- |
         \         27          27 /
```

Here's what I'd like:

```
#1 == sqrt(3) ((2/(9 #2)) + #2) 1i) / 2
#2 == (sqrt(11) sqrt(27) / 27 - 17 / 27) ^ (1/3)
```

That way the output is easy cut-and-pastable into an editor for rapid conversion to code.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB functions `ccode` (or `matlabFunction`) do the trick beautifully.

```
syms x
s = solve(x^4 + 2*x + 1, x,'MaxDegree',3);
ccode(s, 'file', 'outfile.c');
```

Matlab generates `outfile.c` with sparse matrix notation and substitution-simplified computation:

```
t2 = sqrt(1.1E1);
t3 = sqrt(2.7E1);
t4 = t2*t3*(1.0/2.7E1);
t5 = t4-1.7E1/2.7E1;
t6 = 1.0/pow(t5,1.0/3.0);
t7 = pow(t5,1.0/3.0);
t8 = sqrt(3.0);
t9 = t6*(2.0/9.0);
t10 = t7+t9;
t11 = t6*(1.0/9.0);
A0[0][0] = -1.0;
A0[1][0] = t6*(-2.0/9.0)+t7+1.0/3.0;
A0[2][0] = t7*(-1.0/2.0)+t11-t8*t10*5.0E-1*sqrt(-1.0)+1.0/3.0;
A0[3][0] = t7*(-1.0/2.0)+t11+t8*t10*5.0E-1*sqrt(-1.0)+1.0/3.0;
```